# Не устанавливается pycurl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, grab

Когда я пытаюсь установить библиотеку pycurl через pip:

```
pip install pycurl
```

то получаю ошибку:

```
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz (222 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_88cd15710dba4858adf07a8f6c7baf00\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_88cd15710dba4858adf07a8f6c7baf00\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fp9wbsh2'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_88cd15710dba4858adf07a8f6c7baf00\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/1a/35b1d8b8e4e23a234f1b17a8a40299fd550940b16866c9a1f2d47a04b969/pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz#sha256=8301518689daefa53726b59ded6b48f33751c3
83cf987b0ccfbbc4ed40281325 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
.
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.5.tar.gz (216 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_557e908069904ad6bfe12edf7fd010f9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_557e908069904ad6bfe12edf7fd010f9\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-o0s22e8i'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_557e908069904ad6bfe12edf7fd010f9\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/05/4b773f74f830a90a326b06f9b24e65506302ab049e825a3c0b60b1a6e26a/pycurl-7.43.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=ec7dd291545842295b7b56c12c90ffad2976cc
7070c98d7b1517b7b6cd5994b3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.4.tar.gz (215 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_6eb706c1bd1a4eed9d22bbdbf3132532\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_6eb706c1bd1a4eed9d22bbdbf3132532\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ju8yn140'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_6eb706c1bd1a4eed9d22bbdbf3132532\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/52/2c6951c4cd8a4e9288f2561eb9da1dc15b5d0f4e610a7e2acf39bc703281/pycurl-7.43.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=bdc308ff2a16ede41921cb0d88f51bd6cb5208
c6478be9db579789e2e4db2528 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.3.tar.gz (215 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_fc0d2dfefc3c40f3934cca75e5f8d0ce\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_fc0d2dfefc3c40f3934cca75e5f8d0ce\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-outxmcph'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_fc0d2dfefc3c40f3934cca75e5f8d0ce\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/b3/0f3979633b7890bab6098d84c84467030b807a1e2b31f5d30103af5a71ca/pycurl-7.43.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=6f08330c5cf79fa8ef68b9912b9901db7ffd34
b63e225dce74db56bb21deda8e (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz (214 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_31094ce85e494f41bf523c4afa8d1601\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_31094ce85e494f41bf523c4afa8d1601\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6rgf0azz'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_31094ce85e494f41bf523c4afa8d1601\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=0f0cdfc7a92d4f2a5c44226162434e34f7d696
7d3af416a6f1448649c09a25a4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.1.tar.gz (195 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_fa585de583e24f44b6d9c3cf6a72e4cf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_fa585de583e24f44b6d9c3cf6a72e4cf\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bnqn919r'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_fa585de583e24f44b6d9c3cf6a72e4cf\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/d9/d272b38e6e25d2686e22f6058820298dadead69340b1c57ff84c87ef81f0/pycurl-7.43.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=43231bf2bafde923a6d9bb79e2407342a5f338
2c1ef0a3b2e491c6a4e50b91aa (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_6f67a58301dc467594a857214c6d11bc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_6f67a58301dc467594a857214c6d11bc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-wwpaxgwb'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_6f67a58301dc467594a857214c6d11bc\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/3f/557356b60d8e59a1cce62ffc07ecc03e4f8a202c86adae34d895826281fb/pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz#sha256=aa975c19b79b6aa6c0518c0cc2ae33528900478f
0b500531dbcdbf05beec584c (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.21.5.tar.gz (170 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_84645845fb1045f8a24a1cc3fafbcf0f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_84645845fb1045f8a24a1cc3fafbcf0f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-9dal02jh'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_84645845fb1045f8a24a1cc3fafbcf0f\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/fa/37bc18e2f60100d9833cf008dca0861f6815cd1743c3b31a419bc6576ee3/pycurl-7.21.5.tar.gz#sha256=8a1e0eb55573388275a1d6c2534ca4cfca5d7fa7
72b99b505c08fa149b27aed0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.5.3.tar.gz (154 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_71422196aecf4c8ab6e6b4d1640447b3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_71422196aecf4c8ab6e6b4d1640447b3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-cr2xcroi'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_71422196aecf4c8ab6e6b4d1640447b3\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/a2/59761b58683967087aa131e1043b67d6b4675f0d0e68940c3b4d6f9df263/pycurl-7.19.5.3.tar.gz#sha256=24f6c4016b1dd2a5e29d1b025ac2ad61f80c17
adfdcf8a7f47aefab63ace78d7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.5.2.tar.gz (153 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_ed145a0cd259427188502dc28ce0f808\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_ed145a0cd259427188502dc28ce0f808\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-eio2ks_r'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_ed145a0cd259427188502dc28ce0f808\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/35/04e331a7a9e2fdea4b9cadcc23038bd56f80632065258c98730a199fd223/pycurl-7.19.5.2.tar.gz#sha256=98cc821555d152977fac99b6e5cb0f759275aa
bdf14e4928890c6fcc944ab736 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.5.1.tar.gz (142 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_2754272d53b540ec88580eeb377a590e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_2754272d53b540ec88580eeb377a590e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-etuz22sa'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_2754272d53b540ec88580eeb377a590e\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/fb/973d075babcd8cb101d964b898c7b148bb80275344d960c27532b5b35abf/pycurl-7.19.5.1.tar.gz#sha256=6e9770f80459757f73bd71af82fbb29cd398b3
8388cdf1beab31ea91a331bc6c (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.5.tar.gz (107 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_e829d36b1a204580af875ddde42de0c2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_e829d36b1a204580af875ddde42de0c2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8xmpo9k2'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_e829d36b1a204580af875ddde42de0c2\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/48/13bad289ef6f4869b1d8fc11ae54de8cfb3cc4a2eb9f7419c506f763be46/pycurl-7.19.5.tar.gz#sha256=69a0aa7c9dddbfe4cebf4d1f674c490faccf739f
c930d85d8990ce2fd0551a43 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz (116 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_6e99343d4aa84dd8ab7722bb6610bf7b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_6e99343d4aa84dd8ab7722bb6610bf7b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-12jj_wfo'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_6e99343d4aa84dd8ab7722bb6610bf7b\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e9/f3dc93a056957d80b5697f221dbb6a7c114f979bdfa7433bc8e89d723b0f/pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=c0d673fe99a9de07239eabe77c798f1b043f60
c02afaec1430ceaf59d7501a4f (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.3.tar.gz (113 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_561cf2f64c104886980fc81d57defec3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_561cf2f64c104886980fc81d57defec3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-n_8weqfb'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_561cf2f64c104886980fc81d57defec3\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/07/f96744c4d54b30f923194423c93215f71b62fd45d4626af7380ee5aac77c/pycurl-7.19.3.tar.gz#sha256=05e48835fe445ff327dcd373f49d9970e0b828a0
7cd4d08a23264507a742d616 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.0.3.tar.gz (90 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_1624d8526fb8487fbe897eb247876c4f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_1624d8526fb8487fbe897eb247876c4f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-pud9u0ge'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_1624d8526fb8487fbe897eb247876c4f\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_1624d8526fb8487fbe897eb247876c4f\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
        fail("Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl")
    NameError: name 'fail' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/42/1394c2aac756d8c75af612ee4476130e994d56b3fe097f213a1f5db5d272/pycurl-7.19.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=3293c990e076428bc7408c26c787af92fd531e
f63976b1dc45f75eec7480b09a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.0.2.tar.gz (89 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_486e082c4da44d3a903d2f9d815cb46c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_486e082c4da44d3a903d2f9d815cb46c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-7eb7d_of'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_486e082c4da44d3a903d2f9d815cb46c\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_486e082c4da44d3a903d2f9d815cb46c\setup.py", line 69, in <module>
        assert os.path.isdir(CURL_DIR), "please check CURL_DIR in setup.py"
    AssertionError: please check CURL_DIR in setup.py
    Using curl directory: c:\src\build\pycurl\curl-7.16.2.1
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/79/576eaecd19f11a265cd8d10f339ecfd4b1033436e56e6f2625153a4b79aa/pycurl-7.19.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=7a9e793b9181654d5eef3f6d22c244c57d2b51
d38feb4c1b71d68efda99b0547 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.0.1.tar.gz (86 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_7146123e66394c81b3d582096ec6eb54\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_7146123e66394c81b3d582096ec6eb54\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2kmptpwl'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_7146123e66394c81b3d582096ec6eb54\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_7146123e66394c81b3d582096ec6eb54\setup.py", line 69, in <module>
        assert os.path.isdir(CURL_DIR), "please check CURL_DIR in setup.py"
    AssertionError: please check CURL_DIR in setup.py
    Using curl directory: c:\src\build\pycurl\curl-7.16.2.1
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/11/79e2187232ffdb96c9c200f8fc82452f8631f659fd9bdd2acf4bf7991905/pycurl-7.19.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=8b14d91d7453c5d9a4cc8cd4e61ab938929881
3028d10661bf2079ee06d676c8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz (70 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_3064b0fdfb344280a61ea933a3b0f0fe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_3064b0fdfb344280a61ea933a3b0f0fe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-r156jpgn'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_3064b0fdfb344280a61ea933a3b0f0fe\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_3064b0fdfb344280a61ea933a3b0f0fe\setup.py", line 58
        print "FATAL: bad directory %s in environment variable %s" % (dir, envvar)
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/73/abcfbbb6e1dd7087fa53042c301c056c11264e8a737a4688f834162d731e/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz#sha256=8ef0bf1c0e48f0d193ef8ac4ae4b3596a1e91b6c
bf1ff1b25de769fe3782aeb6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pycurl-7.18.2.tar.gz (69 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lolo\pycharmprojects\findword\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5
\\pycurl_5428125dd5a54461ab3f2bc9acfdbbb2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\\pycurl_5428125dd5a54461ab3f2bc9acfdbbb2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getat
tr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lolo\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-opv_mgwm'
         cwd: C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_5428125dd5a54461ab3f2bc9acfdbbb2\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8_pnkj5\pycurl_5428125dd5a54461ab3f2bc9acfdbbb2\setup.py", line 58
        print "FATAL: bad directory %s in environment variable %s" % (dir, envvar)
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/8f/711d436c76938093dd10dae465ccee316c6241cfdada06c5cc3b5c1f74b8/pycurl-7.18.2.tar.gz#sha256=cda1085b7911ca802746d816f37d541165ad1e20
c241d22e4c304ddb2bc81ffe (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycurl
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycurl
```

Как мне установить библиотеку?

Comment: версия python какая? библиотека требует питон версии 3.5 и выше, написано же.

Comment: @strawdog версия 3.9.0

Comment: 3.9, возможно, слишком свежая версия для этой библиотеки. она не является стабильной (стабильная сейчас  - 3.7) и находится в стадии bugfix.

Comment: [как установить](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html) с оф сайта. Python 3.7, pip pip 21.0.1, все залетело как к себе домой. Документация так же ссылает [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487278/ssl-error-installing-pycurl-after-ssl-is-set) при проблемах с установкой